# pyspark table to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have an object type `<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>` and I want to convert it to Pandas DataFRame. But the dataset is too big and I just need some columns, thus I selected the ones I want with the following:

```
df = spark.table("sandbox.zitrhr023")
columns= ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'etc']
```

and then:

```
df_new= df.select(*columns).show()
```

but it returns a `NoneType` object. When I try the following:

```
df_new = df_new.toPandas()
```

It gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toPandas'
```

Do I need to put `df_new` in a spark dataframe before converting it with `toPandas()`? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast it to Pandas Dataframe after calling `show` which print the Dataframe and return `None`, can you try the following

```
df_new= df.select.(*columns).toPandas()
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was probably doing something stupid. Never worked with spark and got little time to learn, that is the main reason I am trying to convert it. Your answer worked and saved me hehe thanks a lot

Comment: Just be careful. When you convert a spark DF to pandas, you loose distribution and your data will lie on the driver. This means you loose all capabilities of a distributed processing system like spark